# Fastest way of selecting row in DataFrame with datetime index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I find that selecting row in pandas is fairly slow.

I have a `df` which has over `20k` datetime inside as index, `50` columns.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
for d in reversed(df.index):
    whatever_value = calculate()
    start = time.time()
    df.ix[d] = whatever_value
    print time.time()-start
```

I tried `df.ix[d]`, it takes roughly `50 ~ 60 ms (printed out as above)` each time. So in total it needs `20k * 0.055 =~ 1100 seconds`

To try to avoid using `datetime` to select, I also used the sequential index number, like `df.iloc[[100]]`, but **the same performance**:

```
i = len(df.index)
for d in reversed(df.index):
    i -= 1
    df.iloc[[i]] = whatever_value
```

---

**Edit**

Another thing I tried is

```
result_dict = OrderedDict()
for d in reversed(df.index):
    result_dict[d] = whatever_value
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict, orient='index')
```

I just use a dict to receive the values by datetime, and in the end, I convert it to a new dataframe.

This way is fater than all above, but the `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` took like `28 seconds`.

---

Is there any way to select the row much faster? I don't need to read the value, I just need to assign values to **each** row in order.

Or is there any way to make the `dict -> dataframe` faster?

Comment: is your whatever_value a constant, or is that just a simplification?

Comment: I think the fastest approach is `df = pd.DataFrame(dict)`

Comment: @WoodyPride it is not a constant, but a calculation taking `1 ms` which I measured.

Comment: Can it be calculated ahead of time, or does it depend on something in the loop? You can assign multiple values at once, which will be much faster than incurring all the lookup overhead on each iteration.

Comment: In a nutshell, you are trying to assign different values for your index right? So as @TomAugspurger said, you know them in advance?

Comment: The performance you can achieve depends a lot on what `whatever_value` is, so we'll need more precision about that :)

Comment: @FlavianHautbois updated the code. `whatever_value` is done inside loop, but before the assignment. Also the `55 ms` is measured purely on the assignment

Comment: @JacksonTale It's still unclear. From your code I'd suppose that whatever_value takes only one value for the whole loop, but it seems that you would go into a lot of trouble if that really was the case, so it would seems it depends on the `d` value?

Comment: It will probably be faster to put the values in a list or array instead of a dict, and convert this one to a DataFrame. Since the order is known and the same as the index, the dict has no advantage over list/array. Something like `pd.DataFrame([calculate() for i in range(len(df.index))], index=df.index)`